# Windows 11 adds blank clipboard entry after copying a selection

Tags: windows, clipboard

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'm out of ideas on this one.

Basically, any time I copy something, a blank entry is added after that. Then I have to open my clipboard to get to what I need instead of the blank entry (can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, or even right click > paste).

This happens on both of my Win 11 machines, whether I'm using Ditto or the native Windows clipboard. Doesn't matter if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, right click > copy, or even right clicking highlighted text in the console.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with Win10 and has been for years. It's related to the clipboard history. Using CTRL+C and CTRL+V instead of right-clicking will drastically reduce the frequency of this problem but it still comes up on occasion and also has trouble when using copy/paste in Excel spreadsheets - either copying and pasting values instead of formulas or treating an xlsm doc as a csv file when pasting. It can be erratic and random about how and when things paste.

I've found that simply using the default copy/paste with clipboard history turned off, then using a 3rd party app for clipboard history is the ideal way to go until MS resolves this...and I don't think they plan to. Maybe in Win 11...

Comment: Odd, it just started happening to me in the last month or so after using ditto for the last 5 years, so I thought maybe I had messed up settings at some point..

Comment: I've used Windows 10 since it was beta and never experienced this

Answer (score 1):

I was blaming the windows clipboard, but today I discovered that my IDEs were causing the problem!

In Rider (and other JetBrains software) the option is called "Don't copy/cut the current line when invoking the Copy or Cut action with no selection"
[image]

In VScode you can add `"editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false,` to the settings.json file or disable it from the settings menu:
[image]