# Windows 10 adds blank clipboard entry after copying

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste, clipboard, copy

Windows 10 adds blank clipboard entry after copying a selection:

[image: Blanks]

I don't know why it happens. I use [murgee](https://www.murgee.com/) maybe it causes this problem?

Comment: try uninstalling it, if that doesnt solve it it is easy to reinstall

Comment: Title: Win 10 Body:Win 11 Which??

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1709198/windows-11-adds-blank-clipboard-entry-after-copying-a-selection) help with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that it doesn't honor all programs you are copying from.  For instance, we have some old VB6 code.  If I copy text in the VB6 editor, it shows up as a blank entry in the Clipboard.  May be the program or editor you are using doesn't work with the Clipboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).